# Is there ever a situation where statistical electrodynamics is needed?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, wick-rotation

I.e. compute the Euclidean path integrals of QED/the statistical field theory of electrodynamics? I have never seen anyone discuss this anywhere and I am wondering why? What if there is just an electromagnetic field at some temperature where we don't need quantum effects? That can happen right?

Comment: All real world measurements relevant to humans are in some sort of thermodynamic limit, and so statistical QED is actually necessary. It is just that they are so difficult to define, even in the zero temperature limit, that we do not have the ability to handle them. We are indeed very lucky that the low temperature (less than boiling water) limit where our lives revolve around, give only very small corrections to the basic vacuum results. When we do condensed matter physics, it is often the case that we do need to consider temperature.

Comment: I am think this is pretty routine in quantum optics and, for that matter, wouldn't Planck's black body spectrum count?

Comment: This might be interesting to you: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.87.013616

Comment: @BySymmetry usually in quantum optics or black body, they only consider one mode so I was wondering if it was done for the field overall